# Display a table above a div without positon: absolute. HTML / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an information table that I want to toggle on and off. But I need the table to appear above another DIV.

I can get the effect I want with z-index and position:absolute on the info table, but is it possible to achieve the same results without pos:absolute? Maybe with pos:relative? I have tried it and it doesnt seem to work.

All the code is pretty simple so far, here it is.

HTML

```
<div id="btnDiv"></div>
<table id="infoTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Objective Details</td>
        <td>Add task(btn) Image</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
```

CSS

```
#infoTable{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;

}

#btnDiv{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
}


.content{
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

jQuery

```
  $("#btnDiv").click(function showNewDiv(){
    $('#popIn').show();
    $("#popIn").css("z-index", 1);
  });
```

Cheers!

Comment: I dont understand, there is a </table>

Comment: by "above", do you mean on top of, or higher on the page..?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I just put them all inside another containing div and gave that div position:relative.

Comment: how does that fix it...?

Comment: I thought it did, but it actually didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. `z-index` property works on any `position` but `static`.

So making the table `position: relative; z-index: 10` and the div - `position: relative; z-index: 5` should help you. Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uSCKJ/

Comment: I know this should work, but it just isnt. Theres quite a bit of CSS in the background as Im building on top of a large application. Maybe something is clashing. Right now, the infoTable just pushes the content table down the page. I think it's more annoying as it's such a seemingly simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Give the table a negative top margin `margin-top: -200px`